# Is Set (collectively) complete for Cartesian categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

This [paper](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/trace.pdf) says that $FinVect_k$ is collectively complete for traced symmetric monoidal categories, in the sense that given distinct arrows in the free traced SMC (over some generating monoidal signature) there exists a strong functor (from the free traced SMC) into $FinVect_k$ distinguishing them.

Is there an analogous result for Cartesian categories? It would seem intuitive to me that $Set$ might be collectively complete for Cartesian categories in the sense above -- but I can't find a reference anywhere. Is this true, and is there somewhere I could find a proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, the answer is yes.
Indeed:

**Proposition.**
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a locally small cartesian monoidal category and let $f_0, f_1 : X \to Y$ be a parallel pair of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$.
Then there is a cartesian monoidal functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$ such that $F f_0 = F f_1$ implies $f_0 = f_1$.

*Proof.* Take $F = \mathcal{C} (X, -)$ and consider $\textrm{id}_X \in F (X)$. ◼

(This is basically a small part of the Yoneda lemma.)